# Build NextJS as a Static Site and serve it in monolithic backend (node Express or NestJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, nestjs

I have a simple project built in:

- Node v16.14
- Express
- Nextjs v13.2

I want to serve the output generated from [Nextjs Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) in NestJS with [Serve Static](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static) or in Express.

The output from my Nextjs build doesn't include an `index.html` file or similar.

How can I implement a monolithic server that handles the API requests and also serves my web UI SPA?

I also tried the instruction from Nextjs' docs and from the answer from Mohssine Oussama. Here's the output I got after running `next build && next export` with the `output: 'export'` option enabled at next.config.js

[image: nextjs output]

Comment: I'm using next version 13.2 and node version 16.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by not having configured an **Image Optimization Strategy**, and this is required when you're generating a Static Site in Nextjs.

There error message logging from NextJS is a bit cryptic. But this issue can be fixed by disabling image optimization in `next.config.js`

This is how my next config file looks right now:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you did this changes

```js
// next.config.js

...
 output: 'export',
};


// package.json
...
 "build": "next build && next export",
}
```

when you will run `npm run build` you will get `out` folder in the root of your project as it shown in the image:

[image: output of export nextjs]

you will have index.html and html of other pages So you can serve this folder with express

Comment: My out folder does not include an index.html file. I will edit my question with the image of the outputs

Comment: can you please provide more information about your project like 
which nextjs version are you use ?
are you using app directory ?

Comment: I'm using next version 13.2 and node version 16.14. I am using src/pages directory and I am not using the API directory neither getserversideprops